# What happens when casting from INT to BIGINT in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, casting

I'm contributing to a project that runs SQL queries on a variety of database types, some of which I don't have access to for testing.  A `SUM()` operation is leading to an overflow for `INT` data types and the proposed fix is to cast it to BIGINT: `CAST(col AS BIGINT)` before the `SUM`.

That works for most SQL databases.  But I see in BigQuery, [INT and BIGINT are both aliases for INT64](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types).

Do I need to worry about an error or performance hit with this operation?  Or will that CAST succeed without a performance hit, i.e., BigQuery will ignore it since it's already that data type behind the scenes?  The Druid docs indicated that's what happens in Druid.

Comment: In the execution graph, the operation `SELECT sum(cast(cast(id as int) as bigint))` is displayed as `$20 := SUM( $1 )`. Therefore I would say, these operations are ignored. Of course, it is not ignored, if you cast to float64 and back to int64.

Comment: If you want to make that comment an answer I will accept it